# SVN readonly non modified files (checkout)

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to make the non-modified files in a local SVN repository read only until someone changes them and the, once commited, make them back readonly?

I don't want to implement the lock-modify-commit pattern. I just want to have local copies readonly and have some sort of "checkout" command that will make the file modifiable. I am looking to make the developer more aware of the files he/she is changing.

Thanks

Comment: This seems sort of confusing to me. If the file can be merged easily (i.e. no lock is needed) and the file is not very frequently changed, why would you want to force developers to click before they can change the file? Wouldn't a big warning comment at the top be enough if the file is special?

Comment: You're asking for exactly the "lock-modify-commit" pattern, but trying to avoid calling it that directly. "Make the file readonly, unless the developer explicitly does something in order to  modify" is the same thing. If your developer isn't able to be aware of the file they are changing, perhaps you should look for a new developer.

Answer (score 2):

The *Microsoft MS-SCCI* interface defines a checkout and lock, checkin and unlock protocol.

So if you're developer tools support the *MS-SCCI* interface then you could use any SVN plug-in that supports this interface.

As an example the [Agent SVN](http://zeusedit.com/agent/) supports MS-SCCI and it has this feature and works with MS-SCCI compatible IDEs like *Visual Studio*, *SSMS* or *PowerBuilder*.

**Note:** I'm the author of Agent SVN.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `svn:needs-lock` property on all your files.